# Premature end of file exception on XML file parsing occurs frequently but not regularly.

Tags: java, multithreading, xml-parsing

I am currently trying to run a thread to read files from a directory and parse it.
The thread is to continuously watch the directory and send the listened file to process to parse.

I am facing "Premature end of file - org.xml.sax.SAXParseException" on continuously placing files in the specified directory using FTP.

I have tried checking for completion of file transfer and there is no error there.
I have not used inputSource/InputStream to read the file. In addition to that, I make sure that I am not reading the empty file. I just used Dom parser parse method to parse a given file.

I will attach both XML file and the java program for further reference.

I have read many blogs and links. However, no luck. Any assistance would be really helpful.

```
  public class DirectoryWatcher implements Runnable {
  private DocumentBuilderFactory factory;
  private XPath xpath;
  private Document doc;

  public DirectoryWatcher() {

    this.factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    this.factory.setNamespaceAware(true); // XML contains name space pattern. Hence without configuration of name
                                            // space, XML will not be parsed
    this.xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

}


@Override
public void run() {
    while (!cancel) {
        try {
            for (String file : directory.list(filter)) {
                doc = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(directory.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + file);
                markAsProcessed(file);
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(interval);
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            cancel = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}

Error while parsing the file xx/parked.xml Premature end of file. 
[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@38661fd
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:///home/sample.xml ;
```